# Array/String of dynamically created textBoxes in Visual Studio - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, dynamic, textbox

I created, dynamically, a number of textBoxes. The user will write input in those textBoxes and then press a button ("SAVE").

I want to save the info from those textBoxes in an array(or string). Is it possible to implement something like this: `for(i = 0; i < the_number_of_textBoxes; i++) MY_ARRAY_or_MY_STRING += textBox[i].Text; //I know this isn't correct`

I'm sure there should be something similar to my "way of thinking", but I can't find it.

If I would always have the same number of texboxes, lets say 2, I could implement it like this: `MY_ARRAY_or_MY_STRING = textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text;`, but my textBoxes are dynamicaly generated.

Here is the code I use (although I don't think it will be of need), my program has 2 Forms (Form1 is noted as frm1) - It has nothing to do with my question, but maybe it helps, idk. If you need more info about what the program does, ask away, I wont write it here, because it may be useless info.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//Add MySql Library
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Proiect
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form1 frm1;
        public int numar_textBox = 5;
        public int numar_eticheta = 5;
        public int numar_groupBox = 0;
        public int LastTextBoxLeft = 15;
        public int LastEtichetaLeft = 15;
        public int LastGroupBoxLeft = 3;


        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            frm1 = new Form1();
        }



        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i;

            for (i = 0; i < frm1.get_nr_coloane(); i++)
                AddNewGroupBox();

        }

        private void Form2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Deselect.Focus(); //Deseleceaza orice element, mutand focusul pe un label fara text
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        /*
        public int verifica_spatii(TextBox New_text_box)
        {
            int i, k=0;

            if (New_text_box.Text == "") return 1;
            else
            {
                for (i = 0; i < New_text_box.TextLength; i++) 
                    if (New_text_box.Text[i] != ' ')
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }
                return 0; // are numai spatii
            }
        }
        */
        public void On_click()
        {

        }

        public event EventHandler Click_event;

        public System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox AddNewGroupBox()
        {
            EventHandler handler = Click_event;
            System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox grp = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            this.Controls.Add(grp);
            grp.Width = 133;
            grp.Height = 50;
            grp.Top = 10;
            grp.Left = LastGroupBoxLeft;
            LastGroupBoxLeft += grp.Width;
            grp.Text = frm1.get_nume_coloane()[numar_groupBox];
            numar_groupBox += 1;
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.Top = 20;
            txt.Left = 10;
            numar_textBox = numar_textBox + 1;
            grp.Controls.Add(txt);
            txt.Leave += textBoxGeneral_LostFocus;
            /////New_text_box.Click += handler(this,);

            return grp;
        }

        private void textBoxGeneral_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ToolStripItem item = (ToolStripItem)sender;
           // MessageBox.Show(item.Text);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string valorile_de_adaugat="";
            int i;

            for(i=0;i<numar_groupBox-1;i++)
                valorile_de_adaugat+=textBox[i]


            //MySqlCommand Salveaza_in_baza_de_date = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO " + frm1.get_nume_tabel_selectat() + " ("+ frm1.get_unirea_coloanelor + ") VALUES(22056, 15, 2000, 2004));
        }
        /*
Textbox myTxtbx = new Textbox();
myTxtbx.Text = "Enter text here...";

myTxtbx.GotFocus += GotFocus.EventHandle(RemoveText);
myTxtbx.LostFocus += LostFocus.EventHandle(AddText);

public RemoveText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
myTxtbx.Text = "";
}

public AddText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myTxtbx.Text))
myTxtbx.Text = "Enter text here...";
}
*/
    }
}
```

*Thank you for your time,*

*Vlad*

Comment: Just create a `List<TextBox>` where you store the created set of textboxes. Then you can use the code to loop over this list and retrieve the content of each textbox

Comment: Thank you for your time Steve, I will implement and come back with feedback :D

Comment: Could you provide a source of information, from where can I learn how to use this "List<TextBox>" please ?

Comment: I use the `grp.Controls.Add(textBoxes);` to create a new text box. Do I need to add it to the list before I create it ? Or after ?

Comment: It doesn't matter when you add it. Just create a `private List<GroupBox> groupBoxes = new List<GroupBox>();` in your form class, and then do `groupBoxes.Add(grp);` in your `AddNewGroupBox` method.

Comment: Then later you can do `string allGroupBoxTexts = string.Join(", ", groupBoxes.Select(groupBox => groupBox.Text));` or `List<string> allGroupBoxTexts = groupBoxes.Select(groupBox => groupBox.Text).ToList();`

Comment: Another way to do it would be to add a common but unique string for the `.Name` property of each one: `grp.Name = "myDynamicGB";`, and then you can just search your controls collection for them: `List<GroupBox> myGroupBoxes = Controls.Find("myDynamicGB", true).Cast<GroupBox>().ToList();`

Comment: Thank you Rufus I almost figured it out, thing is, I dont need the text of the groupBox, I need the text of the TextBox that is located inside the groupbox.

Comment: SOLVED IT :D I had to edit the method given by you `private List<GroupBox> groupBoxes = new List<GroupBox>();` and `groupBoxes.Add(grp);` but just needed to change it from GroupBox to TextBox. Thank you, ur a godsend! =)